# what does the colon do in c?

Tags: c

I was given this example in class and I am unsure what it does.  I understand the colon adds a bit-field, but I am still uncertain about this question:

```
    a = b > 0 ? 3:1;
```

Comment: Your example is not a bit operation. It is a type of if-then-else called the ternary operator.

Comment: I wonder who's upvoting this thing... c-faq, rtm.

Comment: Given the quality of questions here lately, it must be the yearly "Migrate from VB to C challenge"

Answer (score 3):

`?:` operator is called the conditional operator.

If `b` value is `> 0`, the value `3` is assigned to `a` else the value `1` is assigned to `a`.

Take your Kernighan & Ritchie book 2nd edition, chapter 2.11 Conditional expressions, the behavior of the operator is explained.

Comment: More commonly known as the ternary operator.

Comment: It is called a ternary operator, not "conditional". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: @VladLazarenko The C standard actually calls it "the conditional operator", although I agree that "ternary" is more common.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I removed your changes on my answer. I wrote *conditional operator* on purpose. This is the name of this operator in C. The fact that it is also a ternary operator (even the only ternary operator in C) is a quality of the operator, but the standard name is *conditional operator* (see C99, 6.5.15 Conditional operator).

Answer (score 2):

This is the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3f%3a). It's equivalent to:

```
if (b > 0)
    a = 3;
else
    a = 1;
```

Read it as "a = if b > 0 then 3 else 1".

Comment: Hahaha, your link got screwed up by SO backend too, right? :)

Answer (score 2):

`?` is a conditional operator:

```
a = b > 0 ? 3:1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(b > 0)
    a = 3;
else
    a = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the conditional operator (generally called the ternary operator), which is used as a short way of writing if statements.

In general, it can be read:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

So, in your case:

```
a = b > 0 ? 3:1;
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
if(b > 0) a = 3;
else a = 1;
```

The colon in this example doesn't mean anything related to bit fields - it's just the second part of the conditional.